# What happens if I edit the OAuth consent screen on a running service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-authentication

I want to change the privacy policy and terms of use URL of the OAuth consent screen that is currently running in production.

It is necessary to apply for verification to Google in order to change it, but is it possible to process OAuth in the production environment during the verification application?

If OAuth cannot be processed during the verification application, it will affect the service operation, so please let me know if there is a solution.

[image: GCP OAuth consent screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you edit any of the details on your OAuth consent screen, such as the project's icon, display name, homepage or privacy policy URL, or approved domains, you must re-verify your app for branding before publishing adjustments to your OAuth consent screen then the currently approved scopes list is still in effect.

For more information about this topic, see [OAuth API verification FAQs.](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en) This [Google group post](https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-dev/c/gGQKqhzx8QY?pli=1) might also help.